# TLC4502ID with PH sensor

Tags: sensor

[image: Schimetic]

I'm using TLC4502D IC to amplify the PH sensor output as in the diagram. It was observed that the output is lower and not constant( not converging) for the same PH sensor probe when I tested with multiple ICs of the same type. Is there any reason for this improper amplification?

A reference voltage of 1024 mV was given by LM4140 IC to the pin number 5. R7 is 20k and R6 is 10k. I want to have the output in the range 2.8-3.7V (when the prob is connected to some TLC4502D it gives an output in the required range but some don't. I want to find the reason for that)

I want to have the output of the IC in a fixed range and should converge quickly.